# How do I do comments at a Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

What's the equivalent of `#` for Windows `cmd` console sessions, to create a comment?

The operating system is Windows XP.

Comment: Note that `cmd.exe` in Windows is **not DOS** - it's a full Windows application which just has a similar syntax to that of `command.com`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which comment style should I use in batch files?](//stackoverflow.com/a/12408045)

Comment: Note: If you using Powershell commenting is much easier `# this is a comment`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`REM` is the standard way:

```
REM this is a comment
```

You could also use the double-colon convention commonly seen in batch files:

```
:: another comment
```

A single colon followed by a string is a label, but a double colon and anything after it are silently ignored. One could argue that this form is more legible than the `REM` command.

Note that both of these methods only work at the beginning of a line. If you want to append a comment to a command, you can use them with the command concatenation character (`&`), like this:

```
dir & REM a comment
dir &:: another one
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this only work if it's the first thing encountered, as opposed to doing something like `dir :: comment`?

Comment: First an [useful link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php). Then, double colon comments doesn't seem to work inside code blocks (code between parentheses, like in `if`/`for` loops).

Comment: @efotinis, Is `rem` actually a command? Wouldn't `::` be better because it *itself* is being ignored?

Comment: @Pacerier, yes `REM` is an actual command, but it's embedded in CMD.EXE, so it should be pretty efficient. On the other hand, `::` may be faster, since it ignores everything up the end of line (e.g. it doesn't check for chained commands using `&`).

Comment: Keep in mind that using `::` can break your code in some cases, such as being the last line in a code block.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `::` within the if block of an `if` statement also breaks the code

Comment: I also vaguely recall there being a bug that was still around in Windows 7's cmd.exe where using `::` and multi-line codeblocks based on parenthesis (`if`, `for`, etc) resulted in batch scripts breaking if they exceeded a certain length. It happened even without the `::` comments being within codeblocks and presented as cmd.exe seeming unable to read a large portion of the file.

Answer (score 19):

You prefix your comment with the word REM.

```
REM This is a comment.
```

But if you want your comment printed back to you, you should echo it:

```
echo This is a comment you'll see.
```

Comment: Accepting as working, but I'd only have been slightly more surprised if the answer was BTW, like in http://lolcode.com/specs/1.2#comments

Answer (score 12):

The `REM` command only **remarks** (i.e. Say something as a comment) the line from being executed. However, if `@echo off` is not in the batch file that line will still echo to the screen.

To prevent these lines from being shown you can do one of three things.

1. **Add @echo off to the batch file**:
   If you want to hide all commands as well as the REM lines add @echo off as the first line in the batch file.
2. **Change the REM to @REM**:
   If you want to have the commands shown when the batch file is run, but still want to hide the REM lines type @REM instead of REM.
3. **Use ::(i.e. [invalid lable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639875/1697099)) instead of REM**:
   Finally, using the :: as the remark command instead of REM also prevents the echo of the remarked line.

[source](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001313.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer provided by bernhard is incorrect.

At least through win 7,

```
rem comment
```

in a batch file will print in the output.  To suppress printing, use

```
@ rem comment
```

or

```
@rem comment
```

The same goes for other commands, which by default are echoed to the console.

Comment: The command `REM comment` will not print any output to the screen. For a live demonstration, open a Command Prompt and run `echo comment` then run the command `rem comment`. Notice that the `echo` command prints output to the screen while the `rem` command did not.

Comment: I always use `@REM comment` in my batch scripts to avoid them showing up. I would have suggested editing Bernards answer to include using @ before REM in batch scripts to avoid it showing up rather than posting a whole new answer.

Comment: @RobinHood, batch files echo all commands by default (for debugging purposes), that's why it's customary to start them with `@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL ...`. This way you don't need to prepend `@` to all lines and you can easily switch to `ECHO ON` when something goes wrong and you need to do some testing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything started after exit (with a parentheses) is regarded as comment:

```
REM CODE
exit /b 0

(Hi
I am a comment
I am also the same
```