# How do I create a Windows Batch file that does not show the Command Prompt when executed?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have installed a ruby gem called Redcar, which is launched from the command line.  When it runs, it steals the shell until it terminates, so I have to create a new shell window to continue doing command line work.  The shell I'm using is the GITBash shell from MySysGit.

I found a Redcar.bat file which is meant to launch Redcar as a shortcut, I presume, but I don't want the extra command prompt window to open whenever I launch the BAT file.

How do I just run the BAT without seeing the prompt?

Comment: Wish I knew the answer to this +1 for a good question.

Comment: If you are still interested in not showing the console window at all, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289498/running-batch-file-in-background-when-windows-boots-up) is a solution from stackoverflow that worked for me(in my case I didn't put anything in the registry, but where I needed).

Comment: @Kyle a similar question has been asked  before   http://superuser.com/questions/191149/how-to-execute-cmd-exe-silently  mentions HSTART and briefly mentions that a VBS file can launch it too

Comment: Can you update your selected answer? Is it possible and very simple when you know how.. batch file: line 1: `set var1=hello.txt` line 2: `start "test" notepad.exe "%~dp0%var1%"`

Comment: Simply use `::` or `@REM`. 

Source: http://superuser.com/a/843754/101936

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't -- executing a batch file with the built in Command Prompt is going to keep a window open until the batch file exits.

What you *can* do is take steps to make sure that the batch file exits as quickly as possible.  If at all possible, modify the batch file to run whatever program with the `start` command.  By default, `start` returns immediately without waiting for the program to exit, so the batch file will continue to run and, presumably, exit immediately.  Couple that with modifying your shortcut to run the batch file minimized, and you'll only see the taskbar flash without even seeing a window onscreen.

One caveat to this is that if you're running a console-mode program, which many script interpreters are, the batch file will wait for the program to exit, and using `start` will spawn a new console window.  What you need to do in this case is run the Windows-based version of the interpreter instead of the console-based one -- no `start` necessary.  For Perl, you would run `wperl.exe` instead of `perl.exe`.  For Python, it's `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`.  The old win32 Ruby distribution I have downloaded has `rubyw.exe`, which should do the same thing.

A final possibility is to use a 3rd-party tool to run the command prompt with a hidden window.  I've heard of such things but never had a use for them, so I don't know of anything in particular to point you to.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question.  What was really annoying was not that the prompt window appeared but that it had to stay open as long as the program was running.  Now the flash is totally bearable, and not nearly as annoying.  Will check if I can modify script to run rubyw instead of ruby.

Comment: So much thanks for explainig the difference between "python" any "pythonw" -- finally I found the solution to running the python window tools we have without the command prompt in the background.

Comment: ´java.exe´ and ´javaw.exe´ are the same.

Comment: You can - just not in the batch code itself. really there are a number of Qs on here with As about how to hide the command prompt http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way  http://superuser.com/questions/191149/how-to-execute-cmd-exe-silently

Comment: You absolutely can with a simple wscript! You can even create it from within a batch file as .vbs is also encoded in plain text!

Answer (score 26):

I think this is the easiest and shortest solution to running a batch file without opening the DOS window, it can be very distracting when you want to schedule a set of commands to run periodically, so the DOS window keeps popping up, here is your solution.
Use a VB Script to call the batch file ...

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Batch Files\ mycommands.bat" & Chr(34), 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Copy the lines above to an editor and save the file with .VBS extension. Edit the .BAT file name and path accordingly.
Then just run the .vbs file and the magic happens!

You can create a task on Task Scheduler then in the `Action` should be `Start a program` then select this `.vbs` script you created. Depending on your requirements the other properties you can fill and save.

Answer (score 11):

You can run another batch file with START /MIN CMD.EXE /C mybatchfile.bat from within the command prompt.

From outside it will bring the cmd console window but to avoid that, you can **create a shortcut** file with **properties** modified to **start minimized**.

Comment: In Windows 8.1, this option is in Properties -> Shortcut tab -> Run: -> Minimized (default is "Normal Window")

Answer (score 7):

Continuing on Dennis Williamson's answer, you can edit the batch file and append (prepend) `START /B` to the command you are executing.

For example, I have a batch file that runs putty and had the same problem (extra CMD),
so this is how I wrote it:

```
@ECHO OFF
START /B putty.exe -load name_of_my_config_file
```

It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

To do this, use the program [Bat To Exe Converter](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bat_to_exe_converter.html) to convert your batch file to an executable file.

When converting into an executable, you will find an option to run your file as an **Invisible application** in the visibility section. Thus, when you run it, it will run without a window.

[image: Bat to exe]

Answer (score 6):

Give this a try:

```
START /B batchfile
```

**note added by barlop**

start /? says of /B

```
 B           Start application without creating a new window. The
             application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
             enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
             the application.
```

Comment: That might work if I have a command prompt open, but when I am using the .bat I am double clicking it or a shortcut to it on my desktop. I'm trying to avoid having to have a command prompt to launch this program.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not clear as to your issue, but with some of my batch files, I use a "dumy" who's only purpose is to launch the main batch file.

So GO.BAT will have:

```
cmd /c go2.bat %1 %2 %3
exit
```

The exit closes the command prompt window that would otherwise remain open.

And GO2.BAT will have the actually batch file contents that I wish.

```
  @echo off
  set userid=

  if NOT [%1]==[] goto userid:
  set /p userid=Enter USERID:  
  goto set_usr:

 :userid
 set userid=%1
 shift

 :set_usr
 if %userid%==steven goto steven:
 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [RunHiddenConsole](https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/raw/master/bin/hideconsole/RunHiddenConsole.exe)

`hideExec.bat`

```
@echo off
RunHiddenConsole batch.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the /b switch in front of the path. It won't open the second command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

[Indago's answer](https://superuser.com/a/701867/141909) has been the best solution for me so far. The VBS file allows me to run the batch's functionality through the script, preventing the CMD window from happening in the first place. There are a few caveat's though:

1. If your batch requires admin rights, create or use an existing batch that calls the VBS and run that batch as Administrator.
2. With no visibiity, it can be difficult to discern if what you're trying to do is actually running the way you want it to.

With that said, I'd put a little mock set-up/unit test up first to make sure it's working exactly the way you want it to, before integrating it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [cmdow](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/) in the past, and it seems to have worked for what I want.

You'll probably want to use one of the following options:
`CMDOW [window] /HID`

`/HID` hides the specified window

`CMDOW [window] /END`

`/END` closes the specified window

`CMDOW [window] /CLS`

`/CLS` politely asked the window to close (some windows may open a dialogue box)

Hope this helps.