# How to create shortcut that sets an environment variable and then starts a program without leaving CMD window open?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a Windows Batch file that does not show the Command Prompt when executed?](https://superuser.com/questions/233348/how-do-i-create-a-windows-batch-file-that-does-not-show-the-command-prompt-when-e)

I want to create a shortcut on my taskbar that sets an environment variable and then launches a program. Currently my shortcut goes to a .bat file with these lines:

```
set RESGENTOOLARCHITECTURE=Managed32Bit
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

but that leaves a CMD window open for the duration of the program that's launched (in this case Visual Studio). Is there a way I can do this without a CMD window opening or at least without it staying open?

I don't want to set the environment variable on my machine generally, just when I run this program.

thanks!

Comment: Not an exact duplicate question, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Can you update your selected answer? Is it possible and very simple to do.. batch file: line 1: `set var1=hello.txt`  line 2:
`start "test" notepad.exe "%~dp0%var1%"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked answer is right, that you can't using batch files.

I would create a batch file that runs a PowerShell script (PowerShell is here to stay at least for the foreseeable future). Here is the batch file:

```
set RESGENTOOLARCHITECTURE=Managed32Bit
powershell c:\temp\OpenVisualStudio.ps1
```

And here is the contents of your PS1 PowerShell script file:

```
start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Name then whatever you want, but I would name them the same (extension excepted), and put them in the same place.  I wanted to combine them into one file, but it was problematic to set the variable.

I tested this, although I used it to open Word 2010.

Answer (score 0):

**How to run a bat file without displaying the command window:**

Create a new file named 'runhidden.vbs'
Edit it with a text editor and insert the following line:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Set your shortcut to execute this:

```
wscript.exe runhidden.vbs yourbatfile.bat
```

Naturally, path names should be added to *runhidden.vbs* and *yourbatfile.bat* if required. This will execute yourbatfile.bat without showing the command window.

EDIT: To clarify "runhidden" is an entirely arbitrary name. You can name it how you want.