# How to prevent windows idle sleep if there is disk activity?

Tags: networking, windows-11, sleep, disk-activity, idle

Searching for these keywords online is difficult. I'm trying to find out if there are any hardware activity based idle thresholds in Windows (11), that are tweakable or that I can take advantage of, to PREVENT the computer from going to sleep.

Scenario:

- my pc needs to sleep after say 1h of idle (idle meaning: after the disk and or network activity FINISHED + 1h of nothing)
- my pc also needs to receive files via network ftp. (e.g. from a tablet doing backup/syncs)
- my pc needs to NOT go to sleep due to idle if it is transferring files.

So:

- can I prevent sleep based on a network activity threshold?
- or based on transfer / disk / storage activity?
- ?

I don't think I can do this in a task scheduler + application based way, because A. I don't have events for when the application is done, and B. it could just be an SMB transfer initiated by a user/app on the network (no local application on the pc).

Comment: Have you disabled "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the network adapter's as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/310056/8672)?

Comment: @Harrymc hmm, I did recently enable the "Turn off "Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer"." - which is mentioned in your link. I wanted to only allow magic packets, because otherwise the PC would randomly turn on on its own every now and then. Didn't realize this could affect network & pc idle state --- how windows would sleep the lan when there is clear lan traffic is beyond me.

I guess I could try that and live with the random turn-ons. :) I definitely don't want to disable lan power management features because that will quadruple sleep/off power consumption

Answer (score 0):

As you have allowed sleep in Windows to turn off the network adapter,
when sleeping the computer will turn of the adapter, so cannot be
connected from the network.

You need to enable
"Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
in Device Manager right-click on the network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

It may be some related to the mouse movement. There is a small app that does this job. Named “Mouse giggler”, you can find it at: https://mouse-jiggler.en.uptodown.com/windows. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).